# Weird Apache Commons Lang StringUtils.join result

Tags: java, list, hex, apache-commons

I'm getting weird results from Apache Commons Lang's StringUtils.join. Let's say I have:

```
List<String> values = new LinkedList<>();

values.add("120");
values.add("123456789");
values.add("9000");
values.add("en");

byte[] data = StringUtils.join(values, new char[] {1}).getBytes();
```

I expected to have `31323001313233343536373839013930303001656e`, which is `120.123456789.9000.en`, with `.` as `0x01`. But what confuses me is that I'm getting
`5b3132302c203132333435363738392c20393030302c20656e5d5b4340333664303437` instead, which converts to `[120, 123456789, 9000, en][C@36d047`. Is there a gotcha in the way I'm doing this  that's causing the weird value?

Comment: Which `join` method are you using? I'm not getting any `join` method which takes 2nd argument as `char` array.

Comment: Great, it was a stupid error, I really thought it had a method to join a char array into a string, but it was calling StringUtils.join(T... x);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the following method:

```
public static <T> String join(T... elements)
```

> Joins the elements of the provided array into a single String containing the provided list of elements.
>
> No separator is added to the joined String. Null objects or empty strings within the array are represented by empty strings.

So this method calls toString() on the list of Strings and on the char array, and joins the results.

You want to pass a char or String separator as second argument instead:

```
StringUtils.join(values, '.').getBytes();
```